# Как сверстать по сетке уходящий в бок элемент

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Пытаюсь сверстать эту часть, получается через одно место, не понимаю как это нормально верстать по дизайнерской сетке. В моём случае сеткой выступает `.container`
Есть вариант левый и правый элемент сделать absolute, но, мне кажется, такое себе

Вот как нужно сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть такой вариант, но есть неудобства, я не удобно управляю отступом между блоками с текстом и картинкой

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1094px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.link {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #90ee90;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 1em 1.625em;
  background-color: inherit;
  transition-property: color, background-color;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.btn_green {
  background-color: rgb(66, 174, 96);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.btn_green:hover {
  background-color: rgb(135, 189, 29);
  color: inherit;
}

.intro {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(39, 55, 32);
  display: flow-root;
  padding: 60px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.intro__wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 3fr;
}

.intro__right {
  position: relative;
  right: -30%;
}

.intro__right-img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intro__wrapper">

      <div class="intro__left">
        <h1 class="intro__title">
          Security reviews, solved
        </h1>
        <div class="intro__description">
          Using AI and a team of experts, HyperComply automates security reviews and accelerates due diligence, so you can onboard new tools and partners with confidence.
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn_green link" href="">Get a Demo</a>
      </div>

      <div class="intro__right">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/krEC9.png" alt="" class="intro__right-img">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: а если сделать три блока? в первом текст в третьем картинка а во втором ни чего ... и всё это бернуть во flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вот так сделал

```css
.intro__right {
    position: relative;
    right: -10vw;
}
```

```js
const introTitleNode = document.querySelector('.intro__title');
const introDescriptionNode = document.querySelector('.intro__description');
const introBtnNode = document.querySelector('.intro__btn');
const introImgNode = document.querySelector('.intro__right-img');

gsap.defaults({ duration: 1, ease: 'ease' });

const tlIntroImg = gsap.timeline();
tlIntroImg.add(gsap.set(introImgNode, { scale: 1.2 }));
tlIntroImg.fromTo(introImgNode, { y: '40%'}, { opacity: 1, y: 0 });
tlIntroImg.to(introImgNode, { scale: 1 });
tlIntroImg.pause();

const tlLeft = gsap.timeline()
.from(introTitleNode, {
    opacity: 0,
    x: '40%'
})
.from(introDescriptionNode, {
    opacity: 0,
    x: '-40%'
})
.from(introBtnNode, {
    opacity: 0,
    scale: 1.5,
}).add(tlIntroImg.play());
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1094px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.link {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #90ee90;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 1em 1.625em;
  background-color: inherit;
  transition-property: color, background-color;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.btn_green {
  background-color: rgb(66, 174, 96);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.btn_green:hover {
  background-color: rgb(135, 189, 29);
  color: inherit;
}


/* .intro */

.intro {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(39, 55, 32);
  display: flow-root;
  padding: 60px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.intro__wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 450px auto;
}

.intro__right {
  position: relative;
  right: -10vw;
}

.intro__right-img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.intro__right-img_hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.intro__title {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.intro__description {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}


/* .intro */

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .intro__wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    gap: 4em;
  }
  .intro__right {
    position: static;
    right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intro__wrapper">

      <div class="intro__left">
        <h1 class="intro__title">
          Security reviews, solved
        </h1>
        <div class="intro__description">
          Using AI and a team of experts, HyperComply automates security reviews and accelerates due diligence, so you can onboard new tools and partners with confidence.
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn_green link intro__btn" href="">Get a Demo</a>
      </div>

      <div class="intro__right">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jsrx.png" alt="" class="intro__right-img intro__right-img_hidden">
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- .intro__wrapper -->
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я понял, что вы хотели, то вот добавил gap:30px; отступ.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1094px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.link {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #90ee90;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 1em 1.625em;
  background-color: inherit;
  transition-property: color, background-color;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.btn_green {
  background-color: rgb(66, 174, 96);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.btn_green:hover {
  background-color: rgb(135, 189, 29);
  color: inherit;
}

.intro {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(39, 55, 32);
  display: flow-root;
  padding: 60px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.intro__wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 30px;
}

.intro__right {
  position: relative;
}

.intro__right-img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intro__wrapper">

      <div class="intro__left">
        <h1 class="intro__title">
          Security reviews, solved
        </h1>
        <div class="intro__description">
          Using AI and a team of experts, HyperComply automates security reviews and accelerates due diligence, so you can onboard new tools and partners with confidence.
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn_green link" href="">Get a Demo</a>
      </div>

      <div class="intro__right">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jsrx.png" alt="" class="intro__right-img">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: картинка в бок должна уходить ещё

Comment: Куда уходить, за экран?

Comment: обновил вопрос|

Comment: Мне не понятно зачем картинке уходить за экран? Или вы хотите, чтобы картинка шла от правого края браузера до центра?

Comment: Это дизайн ||||